# Forum with Php OOP

Tags: php, oop, forum

I learned PHP OOP basics and to improve my knowledge of that, I am willing to create forum from scratch using OOP. So, can you give me a few tips you think I should know, what classes should I use and etc to improve my OOP knowledge as much as it possible. Thanks.

Comment: Sidenode: Forums are threaded, bulletin boards are flat. OOP coding for the sake of OOP coding is not a good idea, but for learning the schemes I'd recommend trying to build a tree-structured forum. It's a higher difficulty level, but allows you to skip the Thread/Post/Subforum segregation. It else leads to code duplication instead of OO inheritage design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using PHP framework, preferably some that uses [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) (some of them are listed on that page). You will have to write new classes and also you'll see how the work is done in particular framework, which can certainly enhance your OOP knowledge.

As a bonus, many of these frameworks focuses on security issues so you will not have to worry about security of your web application. And after you learn how to use the framework, it should speed up your work.

Comment: +1 for security advantage. Design advantages of MVC over domain objects are debatable otoh.

Answer (score 1):

In begining it is good to create Interfaces of Global Classes. They will help you in application development. A very good practice is a using a Abstract classes. Some Patterns can help you to. Singleton, Decorator, Factory is very comfort for all projects.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at 'PHP and MySQL Web Development' by Luke Welling and Laura Thompson. Chapter 31 is titled 'Building Web Forums'. I haven't read this chapter, but I have read most of the book and found it pretty good.